# Win8タブレットのスクロールをスワイプしたときの跳ね返りの無効化

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Win8タブレットにおいて、縦スクロールバーが発生しているウィンドウをスワイプすることによってスクロールを端まで送ると、ウィンドウ自体が跳ね返る（何かにぶつかった？）ようなリアクションを取ります。

これが鬱陶しく感じてしまったため、開発中のアプリケーション(.Net4.5環境/WPF)では無効に出来るならしたいと考えております。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ie/hh920761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
の方にcssで制御可能な項目として

> スクロールされた領域が端に達したときに跳ね返る

とされていたのですがWPF、もしくはWindowsフォームにおいてこの機能を与えることは可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

単にバウンドするエフェクトを無効化してしまいたいのであれば、WPFの場合、ListBox等のManipulationBoundaryFeedbackイベントをハンドルするのが一番手っ取り早いと思われます。

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        list1.ManipulationBoundaryFeedback += list1_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback;
    }

    void list1_ManipulationBoundaryFeedback(object sender, ManipulationBoundaryFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

参考:
UIElement.ManipulationBoundaryFeedback イベント (System.Windows)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationboundaryfeedback.aspx
連載：WPF入門：第10回　WPFの「入力イベントとアニメーション」を学ぼう (1/2) - ＠IT
http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1103/01/news124.html

Answer (score 1):

端的に言うと`WndProc`で`WM_GESTURE`を無視すれば「[境界域フィードバック](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/dd371416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)」は発生しません。しかしこれだけでは全てのジェスチャが無効になってしまうので、`lParam`から`GESTUREINFO`構造体を取得して状態を確認する必要があります。

p/invoke.netに`GESTUREINFO`の定義が無かったので試していませんが、[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/dd562167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)によると`GID_PAN`や`GF_BEGIN`を確認すれば判定可能のようです。